# How to get any value from any text-box using oracle-adf through button click?

Tags: oracle-adf

How to get any value from a text-box adf component using oracle-adf through button click?

Comment: Please be more precise. Where do you want to get this value? Into a backing bean?

Answer (score 2):

@ Livin,

Your query was not completely clear, so I made assumption that UI had backing bean enabled.

On UI lets have a "Text Box" & "Command Button" for getting this done.

In the backing bean just write a method..,

```
public String cb1_action() 
{

    String a = (String)it1.getValue(); // To recieve value from UI InputText Component
    System.out.println(a);

    return null;
}
```

"it1" is the id of the InputText Component, so now map this method {cb1_action()} to the Action Field in Property Inspector of jDev IDE.

Hope you got it :)

Comment: never mind. i did it using FacesContext and UIViewRoot.thanks

Comment: Where I can find FacesCOntext and UIViewRoot? I mean in which package?

Answer (score 1):

In the textbox component of ADF you have a property called `Value`. By using an `EL` you can set the value in the bean.

Now in the button's `actionListner` you can get the value just by calling the get method of the id that you set in the bean earlier.